# Loopback angular 401 Authorization Required

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

i'm developing app with loopback & angular. I extened "user" modal in loopback into "puser" modal with some addi. fields('reportto'). 
Login & Register for the extended modal is working fine
But when i tried to use the method "find", its showing 401 Authorization required. 

Code:

> `Puser.find({
>               filter : {
>                   where : {
>                       "reportto" : '639124805'
>                   }
>               }
>           }, function(success) {
>               console.log(success);
>           }, function(error) {
>               console.log(error);
>           });`

Please chk the screenshot for req. header.
[image]

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: please share the model configuration json of puser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, loopback protects `find` method to be accessed only the owner rule. 
In order to change it you have to override the model configuration json. (for more information [click here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-ACLs))

For example, to allow public access to all methods add the following acl:

```
"acls": [
    {
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$everyone",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
]
```